# Fix right side bar to browser width

Tags: html, css

I have a header of 130px; and footer of 50px; in between both I place the content.

Content have two bar, one left and on right. I want to fix the height of the right bar in between header and footer. It should not move when move of scroll.

Please tell me how to do it...

or please tell if this js is correct. I want to subract 50px from the window height

```
$(function(){
    vph = $(window).height();
  $('.topicsright').css({ 'height':vph - 50 + 'px' });

});
```

Thanks You

Comment: Can you show for code.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to add  http://jsfiddle.net/jo5z22wu/

```
position:fixed;
```

to your divs

Comment: when we scroll your code thre is a gap coming above the left bar which is same as header height. can you remove this gap ??

Comment: that's how it works but if you fill the height entirely it won't happen

Answer (score 0):

```
div
{
position:fixed;
}
```

also define position top,left or right in css

Answer (score 0):

```
.right
{
position:fixed;
float:right;
height:100%;
}
```

and then just pass it to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use the position fixed.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/xkwbt73v/1/)**

```
position: fixed
```

Comment: when we scroll your code thre is a gap coming above the left bar which is same as header height. can you remove this gap ??

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you ,what type of gap. Will you please explain ? http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/xkwbt73v/3/

Comment: @Maddy What he meant was that the fixed div should stick to the top   it should only be a fixed div once it reaches the top